# Ugly sharp edges when using `rounded corners` in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following picture produces ugly sharp edges

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=black]
    (-2,1) circle (2pt) node  (tl) {} 
    (0,1) circle (2pt) node  (tc) {} 
    (2,1) circle (2pt) node  (tr) {} 
    (-6,0) circle (2pt) node  (ll) {} 
    (-4,0) circle (2pt) node  (l) {} 
    (4,0) circle (2pt) node  (r) {}
    (6,0) circle (2pt) node  (rr) {};
\draw[draw=orange, fill=orange]
    (-2,-1) circle (2pt) node  (bl) {} 
    (0,-1) circle (2pt) node  (bc) {} 
    (2,-1) circle (2pt) node  (br) {};
\draw[>=latex, ->, thick]
    (l) edge (tl)
    (r) edge (tr);
\draw[>=latex, ->,thin, orange]
    (bl) edge (l)
    (br) edge (r);
\draw[>=latex, <->, thick]
    (ll) edge (l)
    (rr) edge (r)
    (tl) edge (tc)
    (tc) edge (tr);
\draw[>=latex, <->, orange]
    (bl) edge (bc)
    (bc) edge (br);
\path[rounded corners=1cm, draw=gray!70]
    (-1-6,1) -- (2-6,1) -- (4-6,2) -- (8-6,2) --
    (10-6,1) -- (13-6,1) --(13-6,-1) -- (10-6,-1) --
    (8-6,0) -- (4-6,0) -- (2-6,-1) -- (-1-6,-1) -- cycle;
\path[rounded corners=1.5cm, draw=gray!50]
    (-1-6-0.5,1+0.5) -- (2-6,1+0.5) -- (4-6,2+0.5) --
    (8-6,2+0.5) -- (10-6,1+0.5) -- (13-6+0.5,1+0.5) --
    (13-6+0.5,-1-0.5) -- (10-6,-1-0.5) -- (8-6,-2-0.5) --
    (4-6,-2-0.5) -- (2-6,-1-0.5) -- (-1-6-0.5,-1-0.5) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Apparantly, rounded corners first calculates the rounded corners, and then joins the endpoints with a straight line segment. the problem disappears if I set `rounded corners=1cm` for the second curve.

How can I get larder rounded corners without the jagged edges?

[image]

Comment: Could someone add a picture of those sharp edges to my question please?

Comment: Edited. Are you talking about that 4 strange parts on the external curve?

Comment: The radius of second path is to big. If you make it smaller, for example 1.2 cm or the same as has inner path, the jagged edges will disappear.

Comment: @Zarko thanks Zarko, I noticed as much myself, see the last paragraph of my question.

Comment: If you persist in selected radius and like to preserve the elegance of path construction, that I see only way to change coordinates of outer path. For example first two rows to \path[rounded corners=1.5cm, draw=gray!50]
    (-1-6-0.5,1+0.5) -- (2-6.5,1+0.5) -- (4-6,2+0.5) --
    (8-6,2+0.5) -- (10-5.5,1+0.5) -- (13-6+0.5,1+0.5) -- ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1cm is also too big and visible if you zoom enough. But for a limited number of operations(mostly path morphing operations), you can temporarily change the settings as you go by putting thinggs inside a brace pair and giving options to that.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[rounded corners=1.5cm, draw=gray!50]
    (-1-6-0.5,1+0.5) -- (2-6,1+0.5) {[rounded corners=0.5cm]-- (4-6,2+0.5)} --
    (8-6,2+0.5) {[rounded corners=0.1cm]-- (10-6,1+0.5)} -- (13-6+0.5,1+0.5) --
    (13-6+0.5,-1-0.5) -- (10-6,-1-0.5) {[rounded corners=0.8cm]--(8-6,-2-0.5)} --
    (4-6,-2-0.5) {[rounded corners=0.8cm]--(2-6,-1-0.5)} --(-1-6-0.5,-1-0.5)-- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was unaware one could do that, thank you!